# Redirecting/Forwarding my JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, checkbox

I have 2 JSP pages linked together. One of them is a form which has multiple checkboxes, you click on the check box, the value is sent to Proto1.jsp where the values aren converted intro strings and it initiates SQL commands. However if no checkbox is selected and the form is submitted, the Proto1 jsp page gives me a null pointer exception. Is there anyway if none of the checkboxes are selected I can redirect the user back to the Checkbox page ?

this is the code for the proto_1.jsp I have, I tried a bunch of answers here, but I still keep on getting the null pointer exception.

```
 portfolio = request.getParameterValues("portfolio");

  String[] portfolio = null;
  if(null == request.getParameter("submit")) {
  portfolio = (String[])session.getAttribute("portfolio");
  } else {
  portfolio = request.getParameterValues("portfolio");
  session.setAttribute("portfolio", portfolio);
  } 

 try{
  OracleDataSource ds= new OracleDataSource();
  //javax.sql.DataSource ds = new javax.sql.DataSource();
  ds.setDriverType("thin");
  ds.setServerName("localhost");
  ds.setPortNumber(1521);
  ds.setDatabaseName("orcl");
  ds.setUser("system");
  ds.setPassword("amex1234");
  Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
 //System.out.println("Connected Successfully");


        Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement() ;
        Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement() ;
        Statement statement3 = connection.createStatement() ;

        if (portfolio!=null)
        { 
            for(int i=0;i<portfolio.length;i++) 
            {   
                pretestList.add(new ArrayList());
                stgtestList.add(new ArrayList());
                mirrorList.add(new ArrayList());
            }
            //  System.out.println(pretestList);
                //System.out.println(stgtestList);
                //System.out.println(mirrorList);

            for(int j=0; j<portfolio.length;j++)    
            { String pretemp="";
              String stgtemp="";
              String mirrortemp=""; 

                ResultSet resultsetpre = statement1.executeQuery("select ID FROM "+portfolio[j]+"_Pre") ; //Put in SQl command and Table name here 
                ResultSet resultsetstg = statement2.executeQuery("select ID FROM "+portfolio[j]+"_Stg") ; 
                ResultSet resultsetmirror = statement3.executeQuery("select ID FROM "+portfolio[j]+"_Mirror") ; 

                //System.out.println("pretemp "+resultsetpre.getString(1));
                //System.out.println("stgtemp"+resultsetstg.getString(1));
                //System.out.println("mirrortemp"+resultsetmirror.getString(1));

                while(resultsetpre.next())
                {
                    pretemp = resultsetpre.getString(1);
                    pretestList.get(j).add(pretemp);
            }
                while(resultsetstg.next())
                {
                    stgtemp = resultsetstg.getString(1);
                    stgtestList.get(j).add(stgtemp);
                }
                while(resultsetmirror.next()){
                    mirrortemp= resultsetmirror.getString(1);
                    mirrorList.get(j).add(mirrortemp);
                }

                //System.out.println("pretest list"+pretestList);
                //System.out.println("stgtestlist"+stgtestList);
                //System.out.println("mirrorlist"+mirrorList);
            }

         } 

   } catch(SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
     %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(request.getParameter("checkbox1Name") == null) //use sendRedirect method
   response.sendRedirect("Proto1.jsp")
else
   continue with your action or redirect to proto2.jsp
```

Comment: So I implement this bit of code in my proto1 jsp page right ? I updated the question with my code, could you tell me where exactly I should implement this ? I tried it in a bunch of places but I still get the same null pointer exception

Comment: which one is your checkbox/ what is your checkbox name

Comment: at the top itself check if(request.getParameter("portfolio") == null ) //use sendRedirect method
   response.sendRedirect("Proto1.jsp")

Comment: "portfolio" is the name of the checkbox, however all the checkboxes are in a different jsp page (checkbox.jsp) which posts the data to proto_1.jsp

Comment: Happy to help always. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check first page check box value before you convert into String then if it is null you can forward to JSP1 from JSP2.

Answer (score 1):

Do NullCheck something like this

```
String myValue = request.getParameter("myParam");
    if(myValue != null && myValue.trim().length() > 0){
//Process Here
}
```

If check box is not checked than you will get that parameter as null.
checking length is optional as per your application

Once you decide that you want to redirect back to the previous page then redirect this way

```
response.sendRedirect('YourJspNameOrPath.jsp');
```

Comment: So I implement this bit of code in my proto1 jsp page right ? I updated the question with my code, could you tell me where exactly I should implement this ? I tried it in a bunch of places but I still get the same null pointer exception

Comment: sorry was away. looks like raghavendra solved your issues.
Let me know if i can help you with anything.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this would be to check for an absence of selected value and to decline the form submission if the requirement for a selected value is not met.

Comment: yes best i to have JavaScript and back end validation as well if required

Comment: How can I go about implementing that ?